# how to install jdk 7 in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, java-7

I downloaded and installed jdk7 on my mac and wanted to find out the actual content of it so that I can install it in eclipse. There is no jdk 7 related content in /System/Library/Java.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to let know eclipse where the JRE 7 is, and you can do in this way :

1. Go to Preferences pane of eclipse
2. Open Java on the left pane
3. Click on Installed JREs
4. Add Button ---> Standard JVM and Next
5. Insert : `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_06.jdk/Contents/Home` in the JRE Home TextBox
6. Next and Save the configuration

[image: Example Configuration]

Comment: thanks, I assume this implicitly requires me to set jdk7 as default so  that I can see the path cause I found it was 1.6 which was my previous version.

Comment: It isn't mandatory, you can simply flag the JVM 7 in the JavaSE-1.7 in  executions environments

Comment: in ubuntu the jvm's are located at `/usr/lib/jvm/`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add JDK 7 to the list of installed JREs in Windows-> preferences -> java -> installed JREs.

Answer (score 0):

It is located in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/... 
So in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home you can find the bin folder, lib folder etc.